# install software with yum as root but run as another user

Tags: yum

What is the best practice when installing a software with yum as root but then you want to run the software as another user?

For example I have to install apache qpid message broker the easiest way is with yum but then I would like to run it as qpidd user ...

what is the easiest way to do that? I would also like to run the qpid as daemon on startup. My target os is Centos7

Answer (score 1):

Installation a software is different than running it. You can install a software package using:

1. Root: this can be done by a package manager like `yum` and the installation is system-wide.
2. Normal user: this can be done by downloading, building, and installing (in a user-owned directory: local install).

Running a software can be run as:

1. Root: when this is required. For example, running process needs to acquire a privileged resource (accessible only to root).
2. Normal user: when no special permission or privilege is required to execute the process or for its job to be done.
3. Root and then normal user: apache is a good example. Web server needs to bind on port 80 (privileged port) and so it requires to run as root. When initialization steps finish, the process drops its privileges to a normal (non-privileged) user.